# Pandas dataframe updating with .loc adds columns and indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm trying to create a software which uses a csv database with pandas for users. I'm not using indexes. My problem is that when I'm trying to update a cell for example: 'Adress' label, it works well the first time but afterwards it keeps adding columns and indexes everytime I update the dataframe. I'm still new to Python and I'm really trying but I couldn't find anything usefull for this one.
This is my code for updating the database.

```
nFirstName = input('Enter new first name: ')
            df = pd.read_csv('../Data/Users.csv')
            df.loc[df['Username'] == username, ['First Name']] = nFirstName
            df.to_csv('../Data/Users.csv')
```

Comment: `df.to_csv('../Data/Users.csv', index=False)`

Comment: I knew it was something related to index = False but I didn't know where to place it. Thank you so much, have a good day!!! @ALollz